# FLA to html5 using swiffy link target _ parent

Tags: iframe, href, google-swiffy

I would like to know if there is a solution a good solution about my problem (i got a solution but  i think  is not a good one)

I got some *.fla* files when they are convertited in swf links between them work very well.

But when i'm convert them in HTML5 by swiffy there no error but links are work like an href with `target="_parent"` but i use them in a `iframe` and i wont like they redirect me... I used sandbox but if i dont `allow-top-navigation` links dont work.

Then i modified `runtime.js` and i search and replace `"_parent"` by `"_self"` and working well but i'm afraid it could cause trouble for some functions.

In the *.fla* the function used is `getUrl()` and the second parameter is `"_self"` ...

Comment: thanks ninita ^^ look better now

Comment: The best solution i found was to modifie runtime.js from google was hard but finaly work and i dont have to modifie every file.
Hopefully because we cant do it since google stop the support and then dont allow convertion.
I found too the way to disable link from a swiffy-output ^^